# переписать код javascript на jQuery

Tags: javascript

```
const navigateToFormStep = (stepNumber) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".form-step").forEach((formStepElement) => {
      formStepElement.classList.add("d-none");
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(".form-stepper-list").forEach((formStepHeader) => {
      formStepHeader.classList.add("form-stepper-unfinished");
      formStepHeader.classList.remove("form-stepper-active", "form-stepper-completed");
  });
  document.querySelector("#step-" + stepNumber).classList.remove("d-none");
};

document.querySelectorAll(".btn-navigate-form-step").forEach((formNavigationBtn) => {
  formNavigationBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const stepNumber = parseInt(formNavigationBtn.getAttribute("step_number"));
      navigateToFormStep(stepNumber);
  });
});
```

Попытался переписать самостоятельно,думаю что сделал много ошибок. Хотя консолька не ругается.

```
 function navigateToFormStep($stepNumber) {
$('.form-step').each(($formStepElement), function(){
  $formStepElement.addClass('d-none')
})

$('.form-stepper-list').each(($formStepHeader), function(){
  $formStepHeader.addClass('form-stepper-unfinished')
  $formStepHeader.removeClass('form-stepper-unfinished')
  $formStepHeader.removeClass('form-stepper-completed')
})
$('#step-' + $stepNumber).removeClass('d-none')
```

}

```
 (function($){
$('.btn-navigate-form-step').each(($formNavigationBtn), function() {
  $formNavigationBtn.on('click', function(){
   var stepNumber = parseInt($formNavigationBtn.attr('step_number'))
    navigateToFormStep($stepNumber)
 })
})
```

})

И код теперь не работает. Возможно,допущены какие критические ошибки. Пытался править каждую строчку кода js и переводить её в jquery.

Comment: и в чем вопрос?

Comment: Да,подправил уточнение.
Еще раз продублирую.
"И код теперь не работает. Возможно,допущены какие критические ошибки. Пытался править каждую строчку кода js и переводить её в jquery."

Comment: js переписать на jquery? зачем????

Comment: Переписывать чистый JS код, на управление библиотекой jquery, которая морально и физически устарела лет так 7 назад... Вы серьезно?) jQuery использовали, когда на чистом JS реализовать функционал с нуля было затратно, сейчас же все, что есть в библиотеке - уже давно внедрено в чистый JS.. Помогать с данным вопросом автору сравнимо с вредительством..

Comment: Друзья,отношусь ко всем с большим уважением.  Я полагаю -на этом сайте можно задать вопрос и получить на него ответ.
Думаю,вы все разработчики. ТЗ такое - переделать js код в jquery.  Более того, весь представленный jquery код - это мой код,который крополиво нагуглил,пытаясь не нарушать логику jquery. То есть,прежде чем обратиться сюда, сам приложил усилия, чтобы решить задачу. Если бы в ТЗ было - "посоветуйте, что лучше использовать js или jquery",тогда ваши комментарии считал бы уместными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты неправильно прочитал описание функции [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/), ты думаешь, что у each() два аргумента, но на самом деле один аргумент - функция с двумя аргументами.

```
.each( function )

function
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
A function to execute for each matched element.
```

Добавил еще парочку оптимизаций, к элементу можно обратиться с помощью this, предварительно обернув его jquery, в итоге код такой:

```js
function navigateToFormStep(stepNumber) {
  $('.form-step').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('d-none')
  });

  $('.form-stepper-list').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('form-stepper-unfinished')
    $(this).removeClass('form-stepper-active')
    $(this).removeClass('form-stepper-completed')
  });

  $('#step-' + stepNumber).removeClass('d-none');
}


$('.btn-navigate-form-step').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    var stepNumber = parseInt($(this).attr('step_number'));
    console.log(stepNumber);
    navigateToFormStep(stepNumber);
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 2px;
}

.d-none {
  border: 0;
}

.form-stepper-unfinished {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div class="form-step">form-step</div>
<div class="form-stepper-list">
  <div id="step-1" class="d-none">step-1</div>
  <div id="step-2" class="d-none">step-2</div>
</div>
<button class="btn-navigate-form-step" step_number="1">button1</button>
<button class="btn-navigate-form-step" step_number="2">button2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Тоже что и у @Jean-Claude только 10 строк..

```
function navToF(nStep) {
  $(".form-step").addClass("d-none");
  $(".form-stepper-list").addClass("form-stepper-unfinished");
  $(".form-stepper-list").removeClass("form-stepper-active form-stepper-completed");
  $("#step-" + nStep).removeClass("d-none");
}

$(".btn-navigate-form-step").on('click',function(){
  const nStep = parseInt($(this).attr("step_number"));
  navToF(nStep);
})
```

Comment: Всё верно,так же сейчас проверил,заменив только navToF, nStep на navigateToFormStep, stepNumber
Как по примеру ниже. Всех благодарю.

Comment: @ПавелРомадов Да я просто сократил названия для удобства (своего) восприятия. Думаю `each` использовать лишнее, под капотом всё равно перебор идёт.. Он хорош чтобы всем с определенным классом дать "что-то", а например одному - не дать, или дать что-то другое..

Comment: Понял,хотя бы польза будет такая,что увижу правильную реализацию each,а то,на сколько я понял,использовал немного не так у себя. От души благодарю.

Comment: @ПавелРомадов На здоровье! :)